# How can I fix my HTTP handlers and different host headers using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-2.0, httphandler

When a site is used with URL **test.com** handlers are not fired. Whereas if the site is used with **www.test.com** the handlers work properly? The site is behind an ISA firewall. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive discussion on URL rewriting on Scott Gu's [blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure DNS resolves both host names to the IP address of your ISA server.

Make sure the ISA server is configured to route both URLs to your server.

Configure your web site (IIS 5/6: Properties, Web Site, Advanced, Add) to accept the additional host header.

Consider configuring the ISA server to permanently redirect to only one of the URLs. This can also be achieved with an additional web site in IIS.